# Why am I getting ValidationException while using ical4j properly?

Tags: java, ical4j

I've tried to build a calendar with `ical4j`. When I'm trying to get the output to a file, it's giving me an exception like given below :

```
net.fortuna.ical4j.validate.ValidationException: Property [PRODID] must be specified once.
```

The code :

```
FileOutputStream icsOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("").getAbsoluteFile()+ "classInfo.ics");
CalendarOutputter icsOutputter = new CalendarOutputter();
icsOutputter.output(ical4jHandler.icsCalender,icsOutputStream);
```

Comment: Hi, can you share part of the code where are you setting the `PRODID`

Comment: ical4jHandler.icsCalendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));

Comment: Is this not working ?

Comment: https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki/Examples#Generating_a_calendar_file - Have you followed this documentation properly ?

Comment: I have added answer plz check. Use VPN to access if you are not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [ical4j documentation](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j/wiki/Examples#Generating_a_calendar_file), you can try this :

```
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar;

// add this :
// create a new calendar
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
cal.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
cal.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
// set other properties by looking at the documentation..

// your code 
FileOutputStream icsOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("").getAbsoluteFile()+ "classInfo.ics");
CalendarOutputter icsOutputter = new CalendarOutputter();
// send the cal reference directly.
icsOutputter.output(cal,icsOutputStream);
```

Plz refer to the docs for more info.